# mathjax font become small in mobile

Tags: javascript, mathjax

This is one of the article in my blog,
http://codecrazer.blogspot.com/2018/09/blog-post.html

It's written in mandarin, but the content is not important to my question. The formula font is important!

My math formula expressed by Mathjax works well in desktop explorer, such as IE, firefox, chrome. However, the font becomes really small when I use mobile chrome. How can I solve it, thank you~